# Replacing the entire XML property of a Node

Tags: xml, vba

I have an XML Doc I'm trying to modify through VBA.

```
<queryresults>
    <record id="1">
        <itemno>111111111111</itemno>
        <modelno>xxx-XXX-XXX</modelno>
        <itemtype>F</itemtype>
        <itemdesc>This is part number 1</itemdesc>
        <unitmeasure>Each</unitmeasure>
        <priceper/>
        <costtype>S</costtype>
        <sellprice>0</sellprice>
        <drawingno/>
        <itemstock>False</itemstock>
        <saleum>Each</saleum>
        <purchum>Each</purchum>
        <unitweight>0</unitweight>
        <weighttype/>
    </record>
    <record id="2">
        <itemno>111115555555</itemno>
        <modelno/>
        <itemtype>M</itemtype>
        <itemdesc>This is part number 2</itemdesc>
        <unitmeasure>Each</unitmeasure>
        <priceper/>
        <costtype>S</costtype>
        <sellprice>0</sellprice>
        <drawingno>xxx###33333</drawingno>
        <itemstock>False</itemstock>
        <saleum>Each</saleum>
        <purchum>Each</purchum>
        <unitweight>0</unitweight>
        <weighttype/>
    </record>
</queryresults>
```

I want to replace the entire XML property for a selected record. If I select the childnode for record 2 I can see all the code in the xml property but the property is read-only. Is there an easy way to just replace the xml property with a formatted string like this,

```
<itemno>222222222222</itemno>
<modelno>Another Model</modelno>
<itemtype>C</itemtype>
<itemdesc>Some other parts</itemdesc>
<unitmeasure>Each</unitmeasure>
<priceper/>
<costtype>S</costtype>
<sellprice>600000</sellprice>
<drawingno/>
<itemstock>True</itemstock>
<saleum>Each</saleum>
<purchum>Set</purchum>
<unitweight>0</unitweight>
<weighttype>lift</weighttype>
```

rather than having to change the values of each item in the childnode?

Comment: Exactly how are you "selecting" the record?

Comment: <code>Dim oXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Set oXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

oXML.LoadXML(MyXMLFileString)

Dim oChildNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Set oChildNode=oXML.SelectSingleNode("//queryresults/record[@id='2']")</code>

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a bit more complex than you were hoping for...

```
Sub SwitchNodes()

    Dim XmlDoc1 As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
    Dim XmlDoc2 As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
    Dim objNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList, rec As Object, recNew As Object
    Dim ch, i

    Set XmlDoc1 = XmlDoc(Range("A1").Value)
    Set XmlDoc2 = XmlDoc(Range("B1").Value)

    If XmlDoc1 Is Nothing or XmlDoc2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set rec = XmlDoc1.SelectSingleNode("//queryresults/record[@id='2']")
    If Not rec Is Nothing Then
        Set recNew = XmlDoc2.SelectSingleNode("//record")
        Debug.Print "Before **************" & vbLf & rec.xml
        If Not recNew Is Nothing Then
            'clear existing
            Do While rec.ChildNodes.Length > 0
                rec.RemoveChild rec.ChildNodes(0)
            Loop
            Debug.Print "Cleared **************" & vbLf & rec.xml
            'copy over
            Do While recNew.ChildNodes.Length > 0
                rec.appendChild recNew.ChildNodes(0)
            Loop
            Debug.Print "After **************" & vbLf & rec.xml
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print "query results record not found!"
    End If
End Sub

'utility get an XML document from some xml
Function XmlDoc(xml As String) As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim rv As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    rv.async = False
    rv.LoadXML xml
    If rv.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error!" & vbCrLf & _
        "  Line: " & rv.parseError.Line & vbCrLf & _
        "  Text:" & rv.parseError.srcText & vbCrLf & _
        "  Reason: " & rv.parseError.reason
        Set rv = Nothing
    End If 'parsed OK
    Set XmlDoc = rv
End Function
```